# React Bootstrap: How to prevent Form from encoding username and password in the query parameter?

Tags: javascript, forms, react-bootstrap

I'm designing a sign-up form using React Bootstrap's Form component. It takes a username and password from the user, and the user can click submit button which is defined as follows.

`<Button type="submit" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}> Submit </Button>`

`this.handleSubmit` is defined as

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log(this.state.email, this.state.password);
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

When the user clicks the Submit button, it does two things

1. Invokes `this.handleSubmit` as expected
2. The browser URL bar shows http://localhost:3000/register?email=katboo%40email.com&password=123

I don't like that the URL encodes username and password in the query parameter.

I can fix this behavior by removing the onSubmit={...} handler from the Button element and moving it to the Form element at top where only the handleSubmit gets invoked but doesn't encode form input values in the URL.

I discovered this by experimenting and by accident. I am wondering if someone can explain what is the difference and what is the recommended way for doing what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You should try to `preventDefault()` **before** logging. What happens is that it does not see your `preventDefault()` being the first thing in the function, so your browser fills the url with that pattern

Comment: I have tried moving preventDefault() at the very top of the handler, but it does not work. As long as the onSubmit handler is used on the Button element, it will always encode username and password in the URL.

Comment: Could you provide your complete implementation of the form?

Comment: I guess that your problem is that you use a `button` to submit. You should use an `input` instead that is of type `submit`